# Global average pooling does not affect training speed

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

As I understand global average pooling should increase training speed. But for some reason it doesn't. I used [Horse Or Human dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/sanikamal/horses-or-humans-dataset). Here's my code:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

target_size = (160, 160)
batch_size = 100

data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
    zoom_range=0.1,
    shear_range=0.1,
    rotation_range=30,
    brightness_range=[0.8, 1.2],
    channel_shift_range=0.1,
    horizontal_flip=True,
)
train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    'data/horse-or-human/train',
    class_mode='binary',
    target_size=target_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)
val_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    'data/horse-or-human/validation',
    class_mode='binary',
    target_size=target_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)
```

```py
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *

base_model = VGG16(
    include_top=False,
    input_shape=(*target_size, 3)
)

for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

layer = Flatten()(base_model.output)
layer = Dense(512, activation='relu')(layer)
out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(layer)

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=out)

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=5e-6), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
```

```py
history = model.fit(
    train_generator, 
    epochs=150,
    steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator), 
    validation_data=val_generator, 
    validation_steps=len(val_generator))
```

Each epoch of training takes about 14 second for this model. The number of trainable parameters is 6,554,625.

```py
base_model = VGG16(
    include_top=False,
    input_shape=(*target_size, 3)
)

for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

layer = GlobalAvgPool2D()(base_model.output)
layer = Dense(512, activation='relu')(layer)
out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(layer)

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=out)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=5e-6), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit(
    train_generator, 
    epochs=150,
    steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator), 
    validation_data=val_generator, 
    validation_steps=len(val_generator))
```

This model has only 263,169 trainable parameters. But time per epoch is still around 14 seconds.

I tried it with bigger *target_size* and other base models, but still time before and after implementing GlobalAvgPool2D are the same.

Please, explain this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably due to:

- Data pipeline is not optimized (no `caching` or `prefetching`) and probably takes the most time and network run time is negligible. See [Better performance with tf.data API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance) and [Analyze tf.data performance with the TF Profiler](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance_analysis) for more info.
- `Dense` layer after `GlobalAvgPool2d` or `Flatten` is highly parallelized (it's basically a batched matrix multiplication) using optimized underlying C/C++ (for example [OpenMP](https://www.openmp.org/), [MKL-DNN](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-optimization-for-tensorflow-installation-guide.html), cuda kernels and many others depending on used devices), hence larger matrix multiply isn't so severe (at least up to a point).
- `Flatten` is faster than `GlobalAvgPooling` as it's a single `reshape` operation (`reshape(batch_size, -1)`), hence what is lost due to larger `Dense` might be gained here.

**Much larger** `input_shape` might make the difference as `Dense` wouldn't fit well in the memory (either cuda or cpu cache), but I expect it's I/O bounded due to image loading.

Comment: Does it mean that you can't use global average pooling in projects if you don't have servers' CPUs and GPUs? As I already said, I tried different base models and `input_shape`, but models were learning equally quickly, but the second model (the one with GlobalAvgPool2D) allways showed worse quality

Comment: You should use `GlobalAvgPooling` instead of `Flatten`. Much less parameters (as you noted) hence more GPU and memory efficient, marginally slower (if at all, all in all shouldn't be), allows for different size of images as pooling is done on a per-channel basis which is constant nor matter the width and height. You should look at your data loading pipeline and optimize it as IMO it's probably the biggest contributing factor to your `14s` runtime. Currently you can't say much about `Flatten` vs `GlobalAvgPool` as data loading takes most time.

Comment: About accuracy (I assume it's what you mean by quality) - depends on the model, some where designed with `AveragePooling` in mind (current and newer architectures like Efficient Nets, MobileNets), older ones (like VGG16 which is pretty old) were created with Flatten, hence might perform better with it. Usually giant grow in parameters isn't worth marginally (if at all) better results.